# Swift networking with non-void completion handler gets error

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler, moya

My goal is to set up a `completion handler` using a standard [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) request call.

Here is my process:

1. Call backend with with a `MoyaProvider` that conforms to my own `BackendAPI` (already set up)
2. Wrap this call in a completion handler to return `[Player]` data (`Player` is a custom class in the project)
3. Display `[Player]` data

Here is the actual code:

```
func getPlayers(orchestraId: String, finished: @escaping () -> [Player]) {
    let provider = MoyaProvider<BackendAPI>()
    provider.request(.getPlayers(orchestraId: orchestraId)) { (result) in

        switch result {
        case let .success(moyaResponse):

            let statusCode = moyaResponse.statusCode
            if statusCode == 200 {
                let data = moyaResponse.data
                let json = JSON.init(data: data)

                let players: [Player] = self.deserializeJSONPlayers(with: json)

                return players

            } else {
                print ("Non 200 for league players data")
                self.debugStatementsFromResponse(response: moyaResponse)
            }

        case let .failure(error):
            print ("Error: \(error)")

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on the `return` line, with the note that Unexpected `non-void` return in void function. However, I have declared my function to be a `non-void` function. What I am doing incorrectly in structuring my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `completionHandler` which you should use if you want to return the value with the current syntax. If you want to use `return players` then you must change the syntax.

Use this syntax instead to make your current code work with the `completionHandler`:

```
func getPlayers(orchestraId: String, finished: @escaping ([Player]) -> Void) { 
    finished(players) // Instead of return players
}
```

Comment: Got it. And when returning, it should be `finished(players)`?

Comment: @daspianist, yes mate.

Comment: Perfect. This did it. Thanks for the help.